# How to specify --content-disposition while uploading file to Aws s3 in MacOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, request-headers, response-headers

Below command I am using to upload `.apk` file to aws s3.

Following command works correctly in windows operation system. But it fails in MacOS

```
"aws s3 sync --acl=public-read --cache-control max-age=5576000,public --content-disposition=attachment;filename=appName.apk ./uploads/folderToBeUpload  s3://bucketName/myfolderName/ --quiet"
```

In MacOs, If I remove `--content-disposition` option it works, But I need that option.

I will get the following Error message in MacOs

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]

Jun 09 15:14:45 start.bash[8904]: To see help text, you can run:

Jun 09 15:14:45 start.bash[8904]:   aws help

Jun 09 15:14:45  start.bash[8904]:   aws <command> help

Jun 09 15:14:45  start.bash[8904]:   aws <command> <subcommand> help

Jun 09 15:14:45  start.bash[8904]: aws: error: the following arguments are required: paths
```

Comment: Why are you using `sync` instead of `cp`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein,I am not more familiar with aws-cli ,when I am reading documentation I thought sync is best suit for me ,because I want to upload all the files inside the folder so...Whether I need to switch to ```cp``` ?

Comment: Ah, okay! You can alternatively use `aws cp --recursive`. The main difference is that `sync` doesn't copy files that already exist in the target. What do you mean by "it fails in MacOS" -- is there an error message, or does something not work right?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein,updated question

Comment: Try wrapping the value in single quotes, eg `--content-disposition 'attachment;filename=appName.apk'`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein,Thank you ,It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zsh` shell on the Mac can be a bit pedantic about parameters. I've found that wrapping things in single quotes (`'`) sometimes works well.

Try:

```
--content-disposition 'attachment;filename=appName.apk'
```